# How to convert huge image from PIL to cv2

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, python-imaging-library

I have a huge PNG image (625000000 pixels) saved in `1` format via PIL library.

I need to load this image from disk and pass it to [cv2.matchTemplate](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/object_detection.html) function.

I can't pass an image returned from the PIL library directly because it requires a `numpy` array:

```
huge_img = Image.open('huge.png')
result = cv2.matchTemplate(huge_img, sub_img, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
```

**Output**

```
TypeError: <unknown> is not a numpy array
```

But if I try to construct a `numpy` array from the image object it throws `MemoryError` exception:

```
huge_img = numpy.array(Image.open('huge.png'))
```

**Output**

```
MemoryError
```

What can I do then? Is there any workaround to use such images?

Comment: Maybe try `scipy.ndimage.imread`?

Comment: Why don't use the image loading functionality provided in OpenCV? (i.e. `cv2.imread`)

Comment: "Is there any workaround to use such images?" More memory, and an architecture that can address it (i.e. 64bit).

Comment: See if this works for you - `np.array(Image.open('huge.png').convert("RGB"))` for RGB imgs and `np.array(Image.open('huge.png').convert("L"))` for grayscale imgs.

Comment: @Dan Mašek Because it throws `MemoryError` exception too

Comment: In that case go for 64bit Python. With an image that size, your working set is bound to be huge unless you go out of your way to get everything to work in-place.

Comment: Are you sure about the dimensions and image mode? A `1`  image is a 1-bit (binary) format with one byte per pixel, so 625000000 pixels should still only take up 625 MB of memory.